# Strange sound at end of rev range when push throttle when parked.

Tags: exhaust, noise

I was just wondering what your thoughts are on this sound I’m experiencing with my Jeep? I have a Jeep Commander 5.7 Hemi 2006 with a Magnaflow 49709 cat (newly installed) and a magnaflow 18″ oval muffler (installed a year or so ago) with stock resonator and pipes between the mufflers and cat. I have new sparks and coil packs and have very recently cleaned the throttle body.
I have a sound issue from the exhaust, it sounds like a flutter/ chug at the end of the rev range (need to listen carefully). It does not give a smooth rev the whole way through it. Really annoyingly, I cannot remember if I was experiencing this sound before the cat was added or not. Have you got any idea as to what might be causing it? Could it be the stock rear resonator as it appears big and bulky, reducing flow and sound. Thanks for any help!

https://youtu.be/y1ELsi7ZDT0

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure I hear anything wrong. Since you have changed the exhaust from stock, there is a possibility the sound resonates thru the system is going to be changed. Does this sound only happen when standing still, or does it also happen when driving?

Comment: @CharlieRB, thanks for your reply. I’m fairly certain that it only happens standing still but I need to listen closer when driving maybe. Can you hear the noise right at the end of each rev, It’s most noticeable on the final rev.